# PHP PSR-12 is this a syntax error in example?

Tags: php, syntax-error

Source: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#43-properties-and-constants

In the 4.3 Properties and Constants section of PSR-12 there is a following example:

> A property declaration looks like the following:

```php
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Package;
    class ClassName
    {
        public $foo = null;
        public static int $bar = 0;
    }
```

But when i try to run this it causes syntax error like this:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) on line 6

Is this a syntax error in the PSR-12 example?

P.S.
For Praveen Kumar Purushothaman. 
My question is about why in the PSR-12 there is a code example that doesn't work in current release of PHP?
So right now this is an error in the PSR? 
Or it was done intentionally by the author?
PHP 7.4 is still a candidate release and officially this code is not working.

Comment: You will need PHP 7.4+

Comment: So right now this is an error in the PSR right?
PHP 7.4 is still a candidate release and officially this code is not working.

Comment: *Throughout this document, any instructions MAY be ignored if they do not exist in versions of PHP supported by your project. - https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#previous-language-versions*

Comment: Agree with you. Thank you for the answer!